# can whole milk with corn starch be used to make caramel sauce?

Tags: sauce, milk, thickening, caramel

I read through some of the other answers about substituting milk for cream in caramel sauce and it seems that the sauce wont thicken because of the fat content of whole milk being too low,....so I was wondering if corn starch would work??

Comment: Why would you want to thicken your sauce? The cream is there to dilute it.

Comment: The mention of other answers makes it sound like you were directly referring to another question - it may help if you link that question, to better show where your question is coming from.

Comment: @rumtscho there is a difference between diluting for flavour and diluting for texture. The cream is there to reduce the sweetness slightly, and to create a very different effect - a richer 'creamier' sauce than just pure caramel, not just to water it down

Comment: @canardgras I agree that the sauce tastes different with cream. I still don't understand what "the sauce won't thicken" means - the caramel does not thicken after the cream is added, it thins.

Comment: @rumtscho - I see what you mean now

Comment: (cold!) milk with cornstarch is commonly used to make simple (faux)-custards, so you'd probably end up with a caramel custard sauce...

Answer (score 1):

@Brooke, I'm not sure you understand how caramel sauce is made. A mixture of sugar and water is cooked (much the way candy is cooked), basically till it reaches a thread stage - 110° to 112°C (230° to 234°F).  After it's finished cooking, the cream is stirred in.

I'm not discussing method but only giving a basic idea. If you were to thicken it with cornstarch, you might make something palatable to put on desserts but it wouldn't be caramel. It's important to cook the sugar till it caramelized.  There's no brown sugar in it. You didn't mention that but others reading this in the future might think it's needed.

It's *possible* you could use evaporated milk instead of cream but there's no guarantee. I've not tried it. Yes, real caramel sauce is rich and sweet but that's the purpose of it and not a lot is meant to be eaten ...or often.